# How to add an attribute 'node-identifier' to transactions subsystem using jboss-cli?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

There's an XML element in `standalone-full.xml`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:2.0">
  <core-environment>
    <process-id>
      <uuid/>
    </process-id>
  </core-environment>
  <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
</subsystem>
```

How to add an attribute `node-attribute="MyNode"` to the `core-environment` XML element? The result should look like:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:2.0">
  <core-environment node-identifier="MyNode">
    <process-id>
      <uuid/>
    </process-id>
  </core-environment>
  <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [quickstart project](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/jts):

```
/subsystem=transactions:write-attribute(name=node-identifier,value=MyNode)
```